# Jenkins trigger another Job from shared Library

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a job that should trigger another job from a shared library both files are in the var folder and are .groovy scripts. My current Syntax looks like this.

```
build job: 'someJobName', parameters: [string(name: 'someString', value: resultString)]
```

I get the error 
"No item named someJobName found"

Why jenkins cant find this script in the var folder?

Comment: I did not get what is the shared library

Comment: @pratikvasa I use this [https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/)